# What is the difference between a variable declared with "var" and without "var" keyword.

Tags: javascript, keyword, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

What is the primary difference between these two approaches. Could someone help me understand. What does it mean if a variable is declared with "var" keyword inside a function?? in both the cases the timer is cleared in 3secs as expected..

```
Approach 1:
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function function2()
{
int=self.setInterval(function(){
alert(int);
clearInterval(alert("in clear"+ int));
},3000);
}
</script>
<button onclick="function2()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>

Approach 2


<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function function2()
{
var int=self.setInterval(function(){
alert(int);
clearInterval(alert("in clear"+ int));
},3000);
}
</script>
<button onclick="function2()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using var you are implicitly putting that variable in the global namespace.  With var the variable is local to the function.

Comment: okay thanks.. but how in both cases the timer is cleared without any issues?

Comment: As they are shown, there isn't a functional difference between the two approaches you described - they both do the same thing whether `int` is in the global namespace or local to `function2`.